# Make complex function more efficient

Tags: performance, vba, recordset

I have a complex function that I will need to run 19 more times, the only parameter that is changing on each run is the very first parameter "statement type" (statement types includes General information, Training, Agency Label, etc).  The function compares a list of parameters to a table of text "statements" and returns any statements that match into a memo cell designed to hold that type of statement.  This design is really necessary, but i am concerned about the amount of time it is going to take to run all 20.  Is there anything I can do to make this as efficient as possible and reduce run time?  Thank you in advance!

```
Function StatementUpdate()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rstStatements As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstCBG As DAO.Recordset
Dim concStatement As String
Dim strSQL As Variant

Set dbs = CurrentDb()

'Working SQL except defaulting to ALL and not sensing partial string match, with added parenth shipment type was working
strSQL = "SELECT [Statement] FROM [St_Gen_Qry] WHERE" _
         & " (([Statement Category]='General Information')" _
         & " And (([Export Country] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Export Country] & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Export Country]='All'))" _
         & " And (([Export State] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Export State] & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Export State]='All'))" _
         & " And (([Import Country] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Import Country] & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Import Country]='All'))" _
         & " And (([Import State] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Import State] & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Import State]='All'))" _
         & " And (([Material Category] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Material Category] & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Material Category]='All'))" _
         & " And (([Sub Category] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Sub Category] & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Sub Category]='All'))" _
         & " And (([Transgenic/ Conventional] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.RegCode & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Transgenic/ Conventional] ='All'))" _
         & " And (([Intended Use] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Intended Use] & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Intended Use]='All'))" _
         & " And (([Permit] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Permit Required] & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Permit]='All')) " _
         & " And (([Shipment Type] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Shipment Type] & "*'))" _
         & " Or ([Shipment Type]='All'))" _
         & " And ([Active]='Yes'))"

Debug.Print strSQL
Set rstStatements = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
Set rstCBG = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT Cross_Border_Grid_Table.ID,      Cross_Border_Grid_Table.St_General FROM Cross_Border_Grid_Table WHERE   (Cross_Border_Grid_Table.ID)= " & [Forms]![New_Shipment_Home_frm]![Text105])


rstCBG.MoveFirst

'loop through each record in the CBG that matches select query
Do Until rstCBG.EOF
    concStatement = ""
    rstStatements.MoveFirst
    Do Until rstStatements.EOF
        concStatement = concStatement & vbCrLf & rstStatements(0) & vbCrLf
        rstStatements.MoveNext
    Loop
        rstCBG.Edit
        rstCBG![St_General] = concStatement
        rstCBG.Update
        rstCBG.MoveNext
        Loop

rstCBG.Close
rstStatements.Close

Set rstStatements = Nothing
Set rstCBG = Nothing
Set dbs = Nothing


Debug.Print "Done"

End Function
```

Comment: IMO the question is more appropriate for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266750/2165759), I've flagged.

Comment: I'm wondering why you put the rstStatements loop inside the rstCBG loop. Nothing changes to the rstStatements loop, so you might as well do that loop once before starting the other.

Comment: rstCBG should only return one record, and that record could have multiple statements returned and added to the memo cell through rstStatements.  Would it be better to do it another way?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code if all categories are run at once. I couldn't test it without the tables, so maybe there is an error somewhere.

```
Function StatementUpdate()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rstStatements As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstCBG As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As Variant

    Dim sSt_General As String
    Dim sSt_Expiration As String       
    Dim sSt_Training As String 
    Dim sSt_Packing As String 

    'Working SQL except defaulting to ALL and not sensing partial string match, with added parenth shipment type was working
    strSQL = "SELECT [Statement],[Statement Category] FROM [St_Gen_Qry] WHERE" _
             & " ((([Export Country] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Export Country] & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Export Country]='All'))" _
             & " And (([Export State] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Export State] & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Export State]='All'))" _
             & " And (([Import Country] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Import Country] & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Import Country]='All'))" _
             & " And (([Import State] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Import State] & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Import State]='All'))" _
             & " And (([Material Category] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Material Category] & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Material Category]='All'))" _
             & " And (([Sub Category] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Sub Category] & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Sub Category]='All'))" _
             & " And (([Transgenic/ Conventional] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.RegCode & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Transgenic/ Conventional] ='All'))" _
             & " And (([Intended Use] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Intended Use] & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Intended Use]='All'))" _
             & " And (([Permit] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Permit Required] & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Permit]='All')) " _
             & " And (([Shipment Type] Like ('*" & Forms!New_Shipment_Home_frm.[Shipment Type] & "*'))" _
             & " Or ([Shipment Type]='All'))" _
             & " And ([Active]='Yes'))"

   Debug.Print strSQL
   Set rstStatements = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
   Set rstCBG = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, St_General, St_Expiration, St_Training, St_Packing FROM Cross_Border_Grid_Table WHERE ID= " & [Forms]![New_Shipment_Home_frm]![Text105])

   With rstStatements
        Do Until rstStatements.EOF
            Select Case rstStatements![Statement Category]
                Case "General Information"
                    sSt_General = sSt_General & vbCrLf & rstStatements![Statement] & vbCrLf
                Case "Expiration"
                    sSt_Expiration = sSt_Expiration & vbCrLf & rstStatements![Statement] & vbCrLf
                Case "Training"
                    sSt_Training = sSt_Training & vbCrLf & rstStatements![Statement] & vbCrLf
                Case "Packing"
                    sSt_Packing = sSt_Packing & vbCrLf & rstStatements![Statement] & vbCrLf
            End Select
            .MoveNext
        Loop
        .Close
    End With

With rstCBG
    .MoveFirst
    .Edit
    rstCBG![St_General] = sSt_General
    rstCBG![St_Expiration] = sSt_Expiration
    rstCBG![St_Training] = sSt_Training
    rstCBG![St_Packing] = sSt_Packing
    .Update
    .Close
End With

Set rstStatements = Nothing
Set rstCBG = Nothing

Debug.Print "Done"

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try!  Right now, running it with only one statement category is taking 45 seconds (which seems excessive). It is only looping 5 times adding rstStatements to rstCBG.  I can't figure out why runtime is so long.  Any ideas?  My concern is that adding 19 more will mean a run time of 18 minutes to pull all the statements in!

Comment: Hi there, it only queries the statements once. The statements are divided into their own string. So it should not take longer then one run of your original code

Comment: Question, I am getting an "item not found in this collection" error on the second parameter under "with rstCBG".  Could it be erroring out because this particular CBG record does not have a St_Help match in this case?  Will instances without a match error out?

Comment: The fields I mentioned are examples. You should build your list of fields in the same way I did. Or you can post all your field names where the statements should go, so I can add them for you. Also the SQL should be amended to query all field names. `Cross_Border_Grid_Table.St_General, Cross_Border_Grid_Table.St_Training` etc.

Comment: I had built some of my list of fields in (waiting to do all 19 until I get the first few working correctly).  I also tried updating the SQL in the new code, not sure I did it correctly since I am still getting that error.  I edited my code above.  The "item not found in this collection" is happening on rstCBG![St_Expiration] = sSt_Expiration.  I'm trying to put any [Statement] with statement category of Expiration into St_Expiration using variable sSt_Expiration.

Comment: Good work so far. I've added the Dim lines and added the fields to the SQL statement. I recommend to switch on 'Require variable declaration'. In tools/options. To add other fields, Add the Dim lines, add the field to the SQL statement, add the Case statement and add it to the recordset Edit part

Comment: One more question, hopefully it is ok.  If for some reason they make a mistake and need to re-run the function, do you have a recommendation on how to do so?  I would assume I maybe need to have a button to clear all the cells so I can pull in fresh data.  Right now if I try clicking the button to re-run the function I am getting a Run-time error 3188.  Could not update; currently locked by another session on this machine.

Comment: I think it may have to do with the instance of the dbs object. You could skip them altogether if you use currentdb. instead of dbs.  Otherwise I can't see why there is residual locking

Comment: In my research, I think I am running into the 2,000 limit on Memo fields.  It seems other developers have found that you can exceed this limit, but once you exceed it the Memo field is locked.  Someone recommended using Forms.frmItems.Refresh rs.Edit.  I am not familiar with how to use this code.  Should it be in the function created to delete the data before re-querying (in the event they need to start over and pull the statements in again)?  Or added to this code?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a form that sets the filter for the rstStatements SQL statement. Those statements are concatenated with double line feeds that you want to store in the one record in rstCBG. This procedure needs to be run multiple times.

You could build the concStatement everytime the after_update event is triggered in one of the filter fields on your form. You can store the concStatement in a hidden field on your form. Then when the function needs to be called, you can just do this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Cross_Border_Grid_Table] SET [St_General]='" & STORED_CONCSTATEMENT & "' WHERE (Cross_Border_Grid_Table.ID)= " & [Forms]![New_Shipment_Home_frm]![Text105]
```

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  The issue is that the exact same code needs to be written with the filter on statement type changing to 19 other types of statements, each getting put into a separate memo field.  So the statement type of general information goes into st_general and then the statement type of help goes into st_help (and so on).  It is kind of a logistical nightmare!  Once these 19 statement types are run and placed in the memo fields (and multiple statements could come in for each statement types), it will generate documents off the memo fields.

Comment: I see. And do the 19 cycles run at once, with the same filter settings in the form?

Comment: Yes, they all run off the same filter settings on the form so they should be run at once.